# If the data type of the value of a variable is short, but the number has only one digit, is it going to use 16 bits?

Tags: java, types

If the data type of the value of a variable is short, and the number is 1, is it going to use 16 bits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On bytecode level, each primitive "<= `int`" (`boolean`, `byte` `char` and `short`) is actually represented as `int` (see [JVMS, §2.11.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se17/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.11.1)). Thus, a `short` will actually consume 32 bits. The value of the `short` does not influence the number of bits used, i.e. each `short` will consume 32 bits.

Arrays of those types, however, use the "correct" size.